# PostgreSQL: display remaining days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table containing list of trainees and I have to find out how many days are left until the end of their practice. The field contains practice start date, and the output should contain a field like "Days(x)". The trick is to display only those trainees who are engaged in training (8 months).
Test values for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "interns" (
  "intern_id" smallint(5) NOT NULL,
  "f_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  "l_name" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  "gender" varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  "pr_st_date" date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("intern_id");

INSERT INTO scheme.interns VALUES 
(1,'Ivan','Ivanov','M','2020-09-22'),
(2,'Natalia','Kurtz','F','2021-01-12'),
(3,'Kristian','Tompson','M','2021-10-20'),
(4,'Libi','Uolsh','F','2021-12-30'),
(5,'Garry','Cutcher','M','2021-01-30'),
(6,'Steven','Larson','M','2021-02-25'),
(7,'Hugh','Laurie','M','2021-03-16'),
(8,'Jonny','Walker','M','2021-01-31'),
(9,'Ketty','Perri','F','2021-05-11'),
(10,'Liza','Torn','F','2020-11-28'),
(11,'Ely','Buggle','F','2021-01-16');
```

I have no idea how to separate negative values for `AGE(CURRENT_DATE, "pr_st_date")` from positive ones, I tried to use this function to filter those interns who haven't started their practice.
Googled almost everything and just got stuck.
PS: I've just started to learn SQL, so sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interns who haven't started their practice could be filtered out using `"pr_st_date" < CURRENT_DATE` as their start date would be greater than the current date.

You may try the following:

The first query shows the logic/result of the calculations while the final query may be what you're looking for. The [`date_part`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html) function was used here

**Query #1**

```sql
SELECT
    *,  
    AGE("pr_st_date") as age,
    DATE_PART('year',  AGE("pr_st_date")) as years,
    DATE_PART('month',AGE("pr_st_date")) as months,
    CURRENT_DATE,
    CASE
        WHEN "pr_st_date" < CURRENT_DATE AND 
              DATE_PART('year',  AGE("pr_st_date")) < 1 AND
              DATE_PART('month',AGE("pr_st_date")) <8 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END as in_training,
    (CURRENT_DATE - "pr_st_date") as days_remaining
FROM
    interns;
```

| intern_id | f_name | l_name | gender | pr_st_date | age | years | months | current_date | in_training | days_remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ivan | Ivanov | M | 2020-09-22T00:00:00.000Z | {"years":1,"days":22} | 1 | 0 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 387 |
| 2 | Natalia | Kurtz | F | 2021-01-12T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":9,"days":2} | 0 | 9 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 275 |
| 3 | Kristian | Tompson | M | 2021-10-20T00:00:00.000Z | {"days":-6} | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | -6 |
| 4 | Libi | Uolsh | F | 2021-12-30T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":-2,"days":-16} | 0 | -2 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | -77 |
| 5 | Garry | Cutcher | M | 2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":8,"days":15} | 0 | 8 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 257 |
| 6 | Steven | Larson | M | 2021-02-25T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":7,"days":17} | 0 | 7 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 231 |
| 7 | Hugh | Laurie | M | 2021-03-16T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":6,"days":29} | 0 | 6 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 212 |
| 8 | Jonny | Walker | M | 2021-01-31T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":8,"days":14} | 0 | 8 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 256 |
| 9 | Ketty | Perri | F | 2021-05-11T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":5,"days":3} | 0 | 5 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 156 |
| 10 | Liza | Torn | F | 2020-11-28T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":10,"days":16} | 1 | 10 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 320 |
| 11 | Ely | Buggle | F | 2021-01-16T00:00:00.000Z | {"months":8,"days":29} | 0 | 8 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 0 | 271 |
| 12 | Bob | Builder | M | 2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | {"days":13} | 0 | 0 | 2021-10-14T00:00:00.000Z | 1 | 13 |

---

**Query #2**

```sql
SELECT
    *,
    (CURRENT_DATE - "pr_st_date") as days_remaining
FROM
    interns
WHERE
    "pr_st_date" < CURRENT_DATE AND 
     DATE_PART('year',  AGE("pr_st_date"))< 1 AND 
     DATE_PART('month',AGE("pr_st_date")) <8;
```

| intern_id | f_name | l_name | gender | pr_st_date | days_remaining |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Steven | Larson | M | 2021-02-25T00:00:00.000Z | 231 |
| 7 | Hugh | Laurie | M | 2021-03-16T00:00:00.000Z | 212 |
| 9 | Ketty | Perri | F | 2021-05-11T00:00:00.000Z | 156 |
| 12 | Bob | Builder | M | 2021-10-01T00:00:00.000Z | 13 |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8YRuyZusxJwGEcaEud5En/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It worked, and the solution was elegant in its simplicity. Thanks a million! :)